# Recyclerview shows only first item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview is only showing one item, the first one, from an ArrayList, when I debug the adapter it shows a getItemCount() of 3, which looks OK, and no running errors as far as I can see, please help:

This is MyAdapter

```
class MyAdapter(private val myDataset: ArrayList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.Holder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                    viewType: Int): Holder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

        return Holder(view)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.textView?.text = myDataset[position]
    }


    override fun getItemCount() = myDataset.size


    class Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var textView:TextView? = null

        init {
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name)
        }

    }


}
```

This is the fragment:

```
class FragmentList1 : Fragment() {

    var myArrayList: ArrayList <String> = arrayListOf("Fausto", "Félix", "Nacho")


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list1,
            container, false)

        var recycler: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recycler.adapter = MyAdapter(myArrayList)

        return view
    }
```

This is fragment_list1.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FragmentList1">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is list_item.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Aqui va el nombre"
         />



</LinearLayout>
```

There is also a MainActivity hosting a fragment_list1.xml, and also nav_graph.xml

Comment: your list_item.xml root layout is set to match_parent it should be wrap_content

Answer (score 6):

In `list_item.xml` change the `LinearLayout`'s attribute:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

because the 1st item takes all available space and you don't see the rest of the items.

Answer (score 1):

You set `match_parent` to your RecyclerView item `height` which cover all the screen. Try to set it `wrap_content`. Check below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Aqui va el nombre"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you try to `scroll` then you can see other items as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your list_item's height is match_parent which covers all the remaining space

And if you have only one TextView then don't write `android:orientation = "horizontal"`

It is by default horizontal

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Aqui va el nombre"/>
</LinearLayout>
```